# Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int' with Expressions

Tags: c#

Here is my code.

```
public class CountryReadModel
{
    public Expression<Func<int, bool>> Id {get;set;}
}
...
var filter = new CountryReadModel
{
    Id = (id) => {return id == 1||2;} //This line give me error
};
...
```

To be honest i don't know what is wrong, and also i can't see any typo

Comment: these kind of questions shows that OP should learn more about programming before posting anything

Comment: The answers below are correct. The reason for the message is that the compiler is reading you code first as (id IsEqualTo 2), which is a boolean (true/false) value, then it tries to OR it with the integer 2, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can't shortcut the || like that. You have to do it like this:

```
return id == 1 || id == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `lambda expression` instead of `lambda statement`

```
var filter = new CountryReadModel
{
    Id = (x) => x == 1 || x == 2 
};
```